# Reworking a C# Azure Function App to use oAuth rather than basic auth to connect to d365

Tags: oauth, azure-functions, dynamics-365

I have been tasked with fixing an Azure function app that's been running for a long time.

It connects to dynamics 365 to update some entities.

Previously it used Basic Auth to do this, thus:

```
IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> orgServiceManagement = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService>(new Uri("https://our.crm.installation.crm6.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"));

AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();
authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = STRING_CONTAINING_USERNAME;
authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = STRING_CONTAINING_PASSWORD;
AuthenticationCredentials tokenCredentials = orgServiceManagement.Authenticate(authCredentials);

OrganizationServiceProxy svc = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgServiceManagement, tokenCredentials.SecurityTokenResponse);
```

From there, various entity operations are performed, using the methods available in the OrganizationServiceProxy object "svc"

However, now that Basic Auth has been disabled, this system no longer works, and needs to be updated to use oAuth.

I have tried doing this by getting an Application id/secret and creating a connection string thus:

```
string conn =
    "AuthType=ClientSecret; " +
    "Url=" + DYNAMICS_URL + ";" +
    "AppId=" + APPLICATION_ID + ";" +
    "ClientSecret=" + SECRET + "; " +
    "LoginPrompt=Never; " +
    "SkipDiscovery=true";
```

and then creating a CrmServiceClient object:

```
using (var svc = new CrmServiceClient(conn))
{
    // do the same queries using the methods 
    // available for the CrmServiceClient objects which 
    // are the same as those available for the 
    // OrganizationServiceProxy object.
}
```

However as soon as any methods are attempted to be called from the svc object, an error occurs thus:

```
[Warning] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an 
instance of an object.at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query)at MyFunctionName.MyFunctionObject.<Run>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\my\source\code\path\run.cs:line 432
```

Is it possible to do an oAuth connection using application id/secret with an object that has the same interface as an OrganizationServiceProxy object?

Otherwise, I will have to un-pick all the OrganizationServiceProxy method calls and figure out what the equivalent would be with an alternative api...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both `OrganizationServiceProxy` and `CrmServiceClient` classes implement the same `IOrganizationService` interface so both can be used interchangeably. Using the new connection shouldn't cause any other change to your code.

The error you're receiving is probably because you're trying to use the `CrmServiceClient`when it has failed to connect to Dynamics. Please update your Tooling Package ([Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/M.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/9.1.0.110?_src=template) if you're working on Functions v1) as old versions didn't support ClientSecret and won't show any errors on connection.

Your connection string looks fine but I don't think you actually need LoginPrompt or SkipDiscovery.

You can run the following code on a Console Application with your details to make sure it works as you'd expect. Please take attention to the `LastCrmError` and `LastCrmException` properties as they'll show you the exact error in case there's one (`IsReady` = false):

```
string connectionString = "AuthType=ClientSecret;" +
              "Url=https://xxx.crm.dynamics.com;" +
              "ClientId=yyy;" +
              "ClientSecret=zzz";
var client = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

if (client.IsReady)
{
    var response = (WhoAmIResponse)client.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection sucesfull: I'm {response.UserId}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {client.LastCrmError}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {client.LastCrmException.ToString()}");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```